# Script selects all inputs instead of just checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i have this script that i use in conjunction with my tabs, so that when the user switches tab, if there are selected checkboxes on the previous tab, they become unchecked (it helps me with my messaging system)

However, as you can see, the problem is that the line

```
var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

selects all the inputs, and it is causing all my textboxes etc... to turn into checkboxes when i change tab, is there anyway i can only select the checkboxes rather than the inputs?

```
var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
        for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
            if(w[i].type='checkbox'){ 
                w[i].checked = false; 

            }; 
        };
```

Here is the code that changes removes the checked boxes, and here is the entire code that controls the entire tab procedure;

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li").eq(<?php print "$eq_id";?>).addClass("active").show(); //Activate second tab
   $(".tab_content").eq(<?php print "$eq_id";?>).show(); //Show second tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
            for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
                if(w[i].type='checkbox'){ 
                    w[i].checked = false; 

                }; 
            }; 

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you're using jquery

The recommended way

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

or the two deprecated ways

```
$('input:checkbox')
$(':checkbox')
```

Also you are changing them into checkboxes in the following statement

```
if(w[i].type='checkbox'){ // <-- you want == to compare and = to assign
```

if you just use jQuery.. you will only need the selector and can remove the if statement all together

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);  // <-- changes all checkboxes to unchecked
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/UFdza/

The above should work in jQuery 1.6+ but if you are still using an older library you can use the following

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/UFdza/1/

EDIT--

You can replace

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    var w = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
        for(var i = 0; i < w.length; i++){ 
            if(w[i].type='checkbox'){ 
                w[i].checked = false; 
            }; 
        }; 

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

with

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {        
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);  // <-- changes all checkboxes to unchecked
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});
```

Yes, as Raminson pointed out `:checkbox` selector has been deprecated.  It's not recommended to use them but they still work

Comment: Please note that `:checkbox` selector is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).

Comment: Ok so, that edit you just made, does that replace the whole of the code i provided in my original post?, or what do i replace with it? Thanks for your help

Comment: I just updated the answer for you.  @Raminson - I added it to my answer.  Weird that it's been deprecated but it doesn't state at all in the `:checkbox` jQuery docs.  http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: @wirey yes, I don't know why they don't directly mention that some of the methods or selectors are deprecated. note that the `if` statement instead of comparing assigns the values.

Comment: @Arken  I'm just guessing that's what you want but if you show you're html structure for maybe 2 tabs it would be easier to get an exact answer

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your condition be `if (w[i].type == "checkbox") {` instead of `if (w[i].type = "checkbox") {`?
If you are comparing use `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```